# Installing Steam on Linux leads to "Cannot install 'libc6:i386'"

Tags: linux, steam

I'm seeing the above error message when I try to install steam on my fresh install of Ubuntu 12.04.

I'm unsure how to proceed obtaining this package.  Does anyone have any advice?

Comment: Is your system 64 bit ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know steam, but the error suggests that you tried to install its 32bit version on a 64bit system. If there is a 64bit version of steam, then better use that one.

Answer (score -1):

My situation: Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS 64-bit on a Asus Eee PC Netbook

How I solved my problem:

Installed Steam using the link from the Steam website

I ran this command in the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-lts-trusty libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-trusty:i386
```

then opened the Steam launcher.

When the launcher opened it started to automatically download the rest of the packages.

****Note: May need to reboot after executing the command